# libGDX does assetmanager dispose loaded textures?

Tags: java, libgdx, dispose, asset-management

I'm trying to read through his [tutorial](https://github.com/HuangHua/CanyonBunny/blob/master/CanyonBunny/src/com/packtpub/libgdx/CanyonBunny/Game/WorldController.java).  However I never saw how the textures were disposed.

Does the `assetmanager` dispose the loaded texture by the `dispose()` call?

Comment: Yes. You could have seen this for yourself by reading the Javadoc: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#dispose--

Comment: Thanks for that quick respond i was just confused when i was looking at the AssetMAnager class "// only dispose of assets that are root assets (not referenced)".

Comment: That's not documentation for users. It's an internal comment in the code. I think the idea there is that they don't want to call `dispose()` on an object that is a "child" of another object because it's redundant. For example, there might be multiple Textures in a TextureAtlas, so `dispose()` only needs to be called once, on the TextureAtlas. If you want to dispose of something that was loaded by an AssetManager, you should call `assetmanager.unload()` on it instead of calling `dispose()` directly on the object.